# Hello World CUDA compilation issues

Tags: c++, c, macos, cuda, nvcc

I'm using the CUDA by Example book and attempting to compile the first *real* example in the book. I'm on OSX 10.9.2:

My source is:

```
@punk ~/Documents/Projects/CUDA$ /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-6.0/bin/nvcc hello.c
nvcc warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
hello.c:6:1: error: unknown type name '__global__'
__global__ void kernel(void) {
^
hello.c:6:12: error: expected identifier or '('
__global__ void kernel(void) {
           ^
hello.c:10:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'kernel'
  kernel<<<1,1>>>();
  ^
hello.c:10:11: error: expected expression
  kernel<<<1,1>>>();
          ^
hello.c:10:17: error: expected expression
  kernel<<<1,1>>>();
                ^
hello.c:10:19: error: expected expression
  kernel<<<1,1>>>();
                  ^
6 errors generated.
```

And my source is simply:

```
punk ~/Documents/Projects/CUDA$ cat hello.c

#include <cuda.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include "common/book.h"

__global__ void kernel(void) {
}

int main(void) {
  kernel<<<1,1>>>();

  printf("oh hai\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I also tested the `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-6.0/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery` example and that built and ran fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated! TIA!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rename your file to `hello.cu`

nvcc [by default](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#supported-input-file-suffixes) sends `.c` or `.cpp` files directly to the host compiler without doing any device code inspection or compilation on them.

There are various [options](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#nvcc-command-options) to change this behavior.